# <hr> doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css

Opening a plain html with the `<hr>` tag works perfect with Firefox. Howerver i did create my own CSS and the `<hr>` line won't show up. So i am demolishing the `<hr>` tag with my CSS but i don't know where. In Chrome and IE it will work without a problem.

**CSS code**

```
hr
{ 
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

---

Got it! I had to use `<br><br><hr>`. It did work without a problem in every browser without the `<br><br>` except Firefox. The `<hr>` was vanished when not using the `<br><br>` in Firefox. Thanks for al the help people!

Comment: I can assure you that `<hr>` does work in Firefox. Here's a jsFiddle example, using your exact CSS code above to prove it: http://jsfiddle.net/nnNp2/ -- I can see the `<hr>` perfectly well there. I suggest using Firebug to inspect the `<hr>` element in your page and see what styles are being applied to it. That might show you where the problem is.

Comment: Your example work flawless. So it has to be something else. But how should I inspect the element if I can't see it?

Comment: It is working now. I will mark my own anwer as correct. Nevertheless thank you for your helping me out!

Answer (score 5):

Test this: http://jsfiddle.net/jvzMK/4/

```
*{font-family:Arial}
html,body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

hr {
    border-style: inset; /* This is already default styling */
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: red;
}
```

Easier way is to use a "fake" `<hr>` by making your own `<div>` with `border-bottom`; http://jsfiddle.net/jvzMK/8/

Comment: Works on jsfiddle but won't work when used on my site...?!

Comment: Are you using the `<hr>` or the `<div>` method I mentioned?

Comment: I was using the method you mentioned. Somehow the `<hr>` was pushed of the screen. It is working now. I will mark my own anwer as correct. Nevertheless thank you for your help!